# Expand a GROUP BY and HAVING resultset

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

Is there a way to expand/get all the records of a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` query?

For example,

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Count(*) as Count FROM table_name
GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3
HAVING Count > '2'
```

Is there an easier way to get all the records rather than going through the result set and doing `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Column1 = 'this' AND Column2 = 'that' AND Column3 = 'more'` for each record.

If it cannot be done due to mysql or some other restrictions is there any other way to get all the data for `query` above?

By expand/get all the records, I mean if the result set is

```
Value1 Value2 Value3 4
```

I want to be able to get all the 4 records.

Comment: What do you mean with "expand/get all the records"?

Comment: He's trying to explain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.Count
FROM table_name AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Count(*) as Count FROM table_name
    GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3
    HAVING Count > '2'
) b
ON a.Column1 = b.Column1 AND a.Column2 = b.Column2 AND a.Column3 = b.Column3
```

This is basically what you described in your question but in a `JOIN`.