# MySQL Show Duplicates

Tags: mysql

I am currently using a version of:

```
SELECT a,b
FROM tbl
GROUP BY a,b
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

I know the results are correct given what actions I've taken on the table. But, it doesn't actually show me the duplicates. The "GROUP BY" clause blocks the other half of the records from showing.

I know this probably has a simple solution, but how do I actually *show* the duplicates? In other words, if there are 110 duplicates, I should get 220 records.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any unique column like an auto increment?  If so, you can group by that instead of a,b.

Comment: @Daniel:  how are you going to get duplicates when you group on a column that only has unique values?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165330/expand-a-group-by-and-having-resultset

Comment: If the duplicates are at the column level, then grouping by a unique column will show all the duplicates.  It wasn't clear to me that we were talking about duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize. Since I knew the limits for field b, I was really using the wrong kind of statement. I ended up going with:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
    WHERE (b = x OR b = y)
    AND a IN (SELECT a FROM tbl WHERE b = y)
    ORDER BY a ASC
```

This gave me exactly what I needed.

Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * 
from tbl DP
join
(
SELECT a,b
FROM tbl
GROUP BY a,b
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
)  xx
where xx.a=DP.a and xx.b=DP.B
```

Not exactly sure of mySQL syntax, but this SQL should work

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a,b, 
 COUNT(a) AS A,
 COUNT(b) AS B
FROM tbl
GROUP BY a
HAVING A > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that what you meant is that tbl has more columns than a,b and possible a pk id.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl t1
JOIN (
SELECT a, b
FROM tbl
GROUP BY a, b
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b
```

Answer (score 0):

I had very much success with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tbl.user_id,
    tbl.duped_value
FROM your_table AS tbl
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT COUNT( tbl2.duped_value ) AS dcnt
    FROM your_table AS tbl2
    WHERE tbl.duped_value = tbl2.duped_value
    GROUP BY tbl2.user_id
    HAVING dcnt > 1
)
```

What it does is it searches for entries that have a duplicate distinct value, like say a video ID from YouTube or something similar which should be unique per a user's entry.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT a,b, COUNT(*) AS nmb FROM tb1 GROUP BY a,b HAVING nmb > 1;
```